# Как поменять местами соседние элементы в списке?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Хочу для списка реализовать обмен значений соседних элементов.
То есть, значениями обмениваются элементы с индексами 0 и 1, 2 и 3 и т.д..
При нечетном количестве элементов последний сохранить на своем месте.

Для заполнения списка элементов необходимо использовать функцию `input()`.

```
l = list(input("Введите элементы списка: "))
l[::2], l[1::2] = l[1::2], l[::2]
print(l)
```

Если без `input()`, то все работает.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как вариант, возможно, c несколько большей читабельностью:

```
my_list = input("Введите элементы списка: ").split()

for i in range(0, len(my_list)-1, 2):
    my_list[i], my_list[i+1] = my_list[i+1], my_list[i]

print(my_list)
```

при

```
Введите элементы списка: >? 2 1 4 3 6 5 7
```

выведет:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']
```

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых нужно правильно разделять вводимые элементы в список. Вы разделяете каждый введённый символ, а обычно вводимые данные разделяют по пробелам.
Во-вторых размер срезов у вас будет разный, а нужно сделать их одинаковым, чтобы не было ошибки. Если вы отрезаете один элемент спереди у одного среза, то у другого надо отрезать один элемент с конца, тогда они получатся одинаковыми и при чётной длине списка и при нечётной:

```
l = input("Введите элементы списка: ").split()
l[:-1:2], l[1::2] = l[1::2], l[:-1:2]
print(l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну и вариант который вообще не читабелен. :)

```
lst_in = input("Введите элементы списка: ").split()
lst_out = sum(list(zip(*list(zip(*zip(*[iter(lst_in+[lst_in[-1]])]*2)))[::-1])),())[:len(lst_in)]
print(lst_out)
```

Comment: что-то вы нахулиганили 

Comment: Зачем же так издеваться над студентами? 

Comment: Это код, который невозможно поддерживать, так нельзя писать ))  Тем более если можно написать коротко и понятно.